# Python Pygame Joystick won't update

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, pygame

I can't get this to update the joystick axis to print the current value. Tried the pygame joystick test and that works, so it's not a joystick-issue.

thank you

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class JoyStick():

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def update(self):
        joystickOne = pygame.joystick.Joystick(0)
        joystickOne.init()
        self.axisOne = joystickOne.get_axis(1)

OP = JoyStick()

while True:
    OP.update()
    print(OP.axisOne)
    clock.tick(10)
```

output stays 0.0:

```
0.0
0.0
...
```

Answer (score 0):

solved it! Forgot the event handler.

```
while done==False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done=True
```

Comment: Instead of writing `while done == False`, you can just write `while not done`